# Difference in Piecewise function

Tags: plotting, list-manipulation, piecewise

I have two piecewise functions that are defined on values of [0,200].
I would like to find out the maximum difference between the two values.

The usual Max[] function does not work because all values the two piecewise functions are integer values and are discontinuous.

I tried this

```
FindMaxValue[EDFh4 - CDFh4, x]
```

EDFh4 and CDFh4 are the two functions defined as:

```
CDFh4 = Piecewise[{#1, #2 <= x < #3} & @@ # & /@ CDFh3]
EDFh4 = Piecewise[{#1, #2 <= x < #3} & @@ # & /@ EDFh3]
```

The functions have vertical and horizontal components, never at the same time.

```
 CDFh3= {{1/30, 15, 30}, {1/15, 30, 40}, {1/10, 40, 50}, {2/15, 50, 60}, {1/5,
   60, 70}, {4/15, 70, 85}, {3/10, 85, 90}, {1/3, 90, 105}, {11/30, 
  105, 110}, {7/15, 110, 120}, {8/15, 120, 125}, {17/30, 125, 
  130}, {19/30, 130, 135}, {2/3, 135, 140}, {11/15, 140, 150}, {4/5, 
  150, 160}, {5/6, 160, 175}}


 EDFh3={{1/30, 10, 35}, {1/15, 35, 55}, {1/10, 55, 60}, {1/5, 60, 75}, {7/30,
   75, 80}, {4/15, 80, 110}, {1/3, 110, 120}, {13/30, 120, 125}, {8/
  15, 125, 130}, {19/30, 130, 135}, {7/10, 135, 140}, {11/15, 140, 
  145}, {4/5, 145, 150}, {5/6, 150, 165}, {9/10, 165, 180}, {14/15, 
  180, 185}, {29/30, 185, 190}}
```

[image]
[image]
[image]
  CDF Values: https://i.stack.imgur.com/teKvX.png
  EDF Values: https://i.stack.imgur.com/pXc3P.png

Comment: it  would help if we had values of `CDFh3` and `EDFh3` to work with

Comment: Hi @Pillsy I have updated the post to include links to the values of CDFh3 and EDFh3

Comment: can you just paste those in as a code block? thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Try

```
Maximize[EDFh4 - CDFh4, x]
(* {29/30, {x -> 185}} *)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do this straightforwardly:

```
CDFh4[x_] := Piecewise[{#1, #2 <= x < #3} & @@ # & /@ CDFh3];
EDFh4[x_] := Piecewise[{#1, #2 <= x < #3} & @@ # & /@ EDFh3];
Max[Abs[CDFh4[#] - EDFh4[#]] & /@ Range[1, 200]]
29/30
```

Comment: Or: `Max@PiecewiseExpand[EDFh4 - CDFh4][[1, All, 1]]`.

Comment: @march Can you explain what the last statement is "[[1,All,1]]"

Comment: `f[[1, All, 1]]` is the same as `Part[[1, All, 1]]`. Since everything in *Mathematica* is an expression, we can take `Part`s of those expressions just like we take `Part`s of `List`s. Look up the documentation for [`Part`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Part.html). @Andre